# C++ How do I reprint values from a loop?

Tags: c++

I am currently making a cash register that inputs 5 values and then outputs those same 5 values on a receipt with the item tax and subtotal. I then have to add together all the item costs, tax costs and so on to produce a total. So Far I have created code to intake five values and set the frame for my receipt. The issue I have is I have no idea how to get all the values entered from the initial loop and put them on the receipt. The only value that is retained is the final value I input. I'm pretty new so excuse my code and if it's not obvious for myself! Appreciate the help!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {

double taxRate = 0.07;
double subtotal = 0;
double total = 0;
float item;
float cost;
float counter = 0;

while (counter != 5) {

for (int num=0; num < item; num++) {

}    

    counter++;
    std::cout <<"Enter the cost of the item: ";
    std::cin>>item;

}


cout << endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Item Cost"
     << setw(11) << "Item Tax" 
     << setw(19) << "Item Subtotal\n";

cout << "----------------------------------------\n";

std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
cout << setw(10) << item << setw(11) << item * taxRate<< setw(17) << (item*taxRate)+item << endl;

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Open the chapter in your C++ book that explains how to use arrays and vectors, and read it.

Comment: Create an class describing the receipt contents, and operations, then pass all 5 values into the ctor, then invoke the method total().    Better yet, instantiate an instance of the receipt, then invoke receipt.getValues() which runs the code you have already debugged, and then invoke receipt.total() to trigger the output you need.

Comment: It's important to have your loops *around* something, not just spiked into your code for good luck.

Comment: @tadman The loop intakes a value five times? Could you elaborate? I'm not sure what you mean. Seems like you just spiked a random comment into a question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik So i went and read on vectors but how would I go about storing the vector values and printing them from the input? From what I read it seems those are predetermined numbers already assigned. I'm trying to print out values that have not been given until input.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN A class would help greatly but I don't think I'm allowed to use those just yet, I appreciate the feedback though!!!

Comment: Appreciate the feedback, like I said I'm extremely new to this language so anything helps. Even if it feels like I just walked into a gym and I'm belittled because I'm not Arnold right off the rip, lol...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for the contradicting statement... stackoverflow.com isn't a tutorial site but you're mentioning how people 20 years ago learned without it... So is stackoverflow here to help people or not, you're confusing me. Nice try with the insult though lol... Also, I clearly opened a text editor and wrote code to try and figure it out hence why I have code pasted in. It's a primitive thought process to not further my knowledge with the resources at hand. Should probably hunt instead of going to a grocery store too. They did it hundreds of years ago.

Comment: How are you going to quote me... and then end off your sentence with the same quote implying that you don't even know what it means. You just used it in a sentence guy.

Comment: UnKnownFubar: your question is off topic, and @SamVarshavchik is giving you good information that you should read if you want to ask future questions on this site. Too many down-voted or closed questions can block you from asking in the future.

Comment: Beauty is found in youth, and little else is expected.  class is found in C++, a little else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by reading on what vectors are and how they work. Get rid of the while loop. You only need 2 for loops to accomplish the task with the way your code is set up.

```
vector<float> cash;
......
......
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the cost of the item: ";
        cin >> item;
        //push items into vector here
    }
.....
.....
for (int i = 0; i < cash.size(); i++)
{
    // output like you were doing but with your vector elements
}
```

With that skeleton code you should be able to accomplish what you want with a little research